# SELECT typarray FROM pg_type WHERE typname = 'citext'

Tags: django, django-debug-toolbar, django-postgresql

```
SELECT typarray FROM pg_type WHERE typname = 'citext'
```

Why I am getting this query in django debug panel and what does it mean? Whenever I navigate to the new page, this query gets run as 1st then all others, same thing in the python shell using connection.queries command. I am using django 1.11 and postgres 9.6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[citex](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/citext.html) is a PostgreSQL extension and has no fixed typarray so the following query needs to be executed to query [pg_type](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/catalog-pg-type.html) on Django side to register extension with psycopg2

Why you see this query being executed each time you load page is because it is not cached internally which seems to be sorted for Django 2.0

Also note that following query is not called for Django versions before 1.11 as citext is implemented in Django around version 1.11.

Comment: Hvala na odgovoru.

Comment: You are welcome, here you can see the culprit code :) https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/1.11.x/django/contrib/postgres/signals.py